# How to pass a pexpect spawn object

Tags: python, pexpect

How to pass a pexpect spawn object as argument from one python file to another. I tried to pass it, but the error is that it has to be a string. Then I converted the object to string. But it's not working as expected.

Comment: Do you mean from one python process to another?

Comment: yes. in two separate python files.

Comment: from one file to another.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way to pass complex object *directly* between two python programs even one spawns another. You should serialise object state and then pass it. other side should deserialise it before use.

If you want to pass data with command-line argument, you should use string object (not bytes, but string). Please note, that `repr` may not give string which you can use to create “clone”.

Also you can pass data with external files, IPC, TCP, UDP, FIFO or many other ways.

Comment: Can you share with me more details? The spawn object is a ssh session. My goal is to open the session in the first python program, and then reuse it in the second python program without closing it.

Comment: You can use `paramiko` to make connections via SSH inside python without spawning new processes.

Comment: What would be the difference between using paramiko and pexpect.spawn to ssh? Don't I still need to initiate SSH connection again in the second python program?

Comment: 1) You spend a lot of resources and time with spawning new processes. 2) you depend on environment, SSH vendor and version. 3) you have more control on connection.